# Density map based on the sum of a varialble by year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope you guys can help me. I am doing a report for my company. I have historical information (10 years) by week of sales of our company as well as our competitors.

I am trying to do a density map using ggplot. It would look exactly similar than [this one](http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/business/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-29%20at%2012.35.25%20PM.png):

[image]

So I would like to have the X axis as the dates and the Y axis as a % of each vendor sales relative to the total aggregated sales of all the vendors.

I have a file with a column for the week, a column for the vendor and a column for the weekly sales of that vendor.

Is this something that can be done using `geom_density`?

Comment: That looks like an area plot to me, not a kernel density plot.  I suggest you use `geom_area()`.

Comment: hmm... that would make sense. Let me try and see if that works. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Get some data in long format, p

```
p <- structure(list(plot = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), time = c(1986, 1987, 1998, 2010, 1986, 1987, 1998, 2010, 
1986, 1987, 1998, 2010), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABBA", "PIRU", "BECO"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.557407905350901, NaN, 0.316510695187166, 0.301356485920244, 
    0.213498252218338, NaN, 0.17028743315508, 0.180391321330919, 
    0.0244689432643184, NaN, 0.0217245989304813, 0.020595859522034
    )), .Names = c("plot", "time", "id", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

plot it:

```
ggplot(p, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_area()
```